# Phoenix multipart file upload results in 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm making a multipart upload. Its request headers look like:

```
Accept:application/json,text/javascript
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:733
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9Am5omyM263xjTB2
Host:localhost:4200
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/users/asdf/profile
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1
```

I'm getting `415 Unsupported Media Type` as a response. However, I believe Phoenix is configured to accept multipart requests. In my config:

```
config :mime, :types, %{
  "application/vnd.api+json" => ["json-api"],
  "multipart/form-data" => ["multipart"]
}
```

And in my router:

```
plug :accepts, ["json", "json-api", "multipart"]
```

Any idea what's going on? I wonder if it has to do with the `Accept-Enconding`?

Comment: Just to confirm, have you recompiled `mime` after adding that config? See https://github.com/elixir-plug/mime#usage.

Comment: I have! Though that would have been a good catch. I'm beginning to think it's because the `Content-Type` has `boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9Am5omyM263xjTB2` appended to it. Do you think that might cause the issue?

Comment: have you try to delete `_build` folder?

Comment: Thanks, @ardhitama. This was due to me routing the request through ja_serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I was piping the request through ja_serializer. In particular, due to [this line](https://github.com/vt-elixir/ja_serializer/blob/417e11593e0e95b747661ef09fab8a500555906c/lib/ja_serializer/content_type_negotiation.ex#L38). Obviously, this wasn’t a json:api request, so it shouldn’t have been piped through there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After you configure the mime project in your config/config.exs (xml for example):

```
config :mime, :types, %{
  "application/xml" => ["xml"]
}
```

And then run `mix deps.clean --build mime` to force mime to be recompiled across all environments. You should be good to go now.

You can check if it's being recognized as a mime type I.E:

```
iex -S mix
iex> MIME.extensions("application/xml")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error persists. Any other ideas? Could it be the Accept-Encoding' Or pperhaps the presence of the `boundary` in the Content-Type?